# Need help figuring out an Adapter "tutorial" on Google's Android Developer Site

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter, android-gridview, android-cursor

I am currently trying to display database information in my Android app.
I want the data displayed in a tabular form:

```
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| column 1 | column 2 | ... | column n |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| xxxx     | xxxx     | ... | nnnn     |
| yyyy     | yyyy     | ... | nnnn     |
| ....     | ....     | ... | nnnn     |
| zzzz     | zzzz     | ... | nnnn     |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

In looking at the information [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews), it looks like I need to use a GridView with a  SimpleCursorAdapter.

So, I created a DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. In that class, I have a method that returns a Cursor for a query:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabaseName";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "myDatabaseTableName";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public static final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

public Cursor getDataCursor(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return sqliteDB.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
}
```

One section of the "tutorial" on that Google Dev page states:

> For example, if you want to create a list of people's names and phone numbers, you can perform a query that returns a Cursor containing a row for each person and columns for the names and numbers. You then create a string array specifying which columns from the Cursor you want in the layout for each result and an integer array specifying the corresponding views that each column should be placed

Then has this code:

```
String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
int[] toViews = {R.id.display_name, R.id.phone_number};
```

So, in my MainActivity.java I create a new instance of my DatabaseHelper, and get a Cursor:

```
DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
Cursor myDataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
```

What I cannot figure out is, what is "ContactsContract" in Google's snippet above? I thought it might be their Cursor, but my cursor does not have "Data" or "CommonDataKinds" methods available to it. I did some poking around Google's API guides pages to see where they defined those methods, but cannot seem to locate them. I also cannot figure out where they got "R.layout.person_name_and_number" in that same example.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

**EDIT:**

I have added this code to my code to MainActivity.java:

```
DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
Cursor myDataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
String[] fromColumns = {"_id", "columnA","columnB","...","columnN"};
int[] toViews = {R.id.id_textview, R.id.columnA_textview, R.id.columnB_textview, ... , R.id.columnN_textview};
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_new_layout, myDataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.row_of_data);
myListView.setAdapter(sca);
```

And I created a new view called my_new_layout.xml:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/row_of_data">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/id_textview" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/columnA_textview" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/columnB_textview" />
    ...
    <TextView android:id="@+id/columnN_textview" />
</ListView>
```

And then I added my new view to activity_main.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/"my_new_layout />
```

However, now when I try to run the application, I get the error:

```
java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception addview(view, layoutparams) is not supported in adapterview
```

And I get this error, strangely enough, where I include my new layout into activity_main.xml.

Comment: I guess that in their example they are taking the data out of the device contacts.

Comment: Ah, so this is not a DB query whey they say "you can perform a query that returns a Cursor"? If not, can you suggest a better place for me to find information on how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You could fill a Cursor by using a `rawQuery()` (which allows you to write something like "SELECT [column list] FROM aTable WHERE [condition list]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` and it's constructor you can see

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

**Parameters**

- `context`:    The context where the ListView associated with this SimpleListItemFactory is running
- `layout`: resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
- `c`:  The database cursor. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
- `from`:   A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
- `to`: The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
- `flags`:  Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter, as per CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int).

**fromColumns** are the names of the columns of your table, which you would like to get data from

**toViews** are the ids of your `TextView`s that should be inside the XML layout for your row (second parameter in constructor - `int layout`).

Number of items in both arrays should be the same.

Comment: Ok, so I am creating a new layout file that represents a single row of the table I would like to display. Is this correct? Also, when you say "The layout file should include at least those named views defined in 'to'", do you mean android:id="@+id/column_name", then column_name should match a column name from my DB query?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new layout file for your row, and that layout file *should include at least those named view defined in 'to / toViews array'*. Those have nothing in common with the database, but the ones in from / fromColumns do.

Comment: Ok, I thought I finally got things set up properly with a layout, but now I am getting the error "android java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception addview(view, layoutparams)". Any ideas?

Comment: I have added my new code under the "EDIT" section. Thanks.

Comment: You got it wrong... your MainActivity layout, should just include a `<Listview ... \>` without any TextViews inside. Those TextViews should be in a seperate XML file, which you pass to your `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Re arrange your code and if you have any problems, tell me.

Comment: I tried sticking <TextView ... /><TextView ... /><TextView ... /> ... <TextView ... /> into a layout.xml file by itself, and get a "multiple root tags" error in AndroidStudio. I am under the assumption that there needs to be one root view surrounding multiple views. That is why I wrapped all of the TextView views in one ListView view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99155/discussion-between-marko-and-brian).

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your SQL command shouldn't be this. `"SELECT * FROM MyDatabase";`

Either your table name is misleading or you have an error in your logic.

`"SELECT * FROM MyDatabase";` should be (logically) `"SELECT * FROM MyTable";`

That could be why your cursor isn't returning what you are expecting.

---

About the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` it is just a static class that contains constants.

The following pattern allows you to have a class with all of your strings in an organized location.

This also helps you by allowing IDE code-auto-complete to help you not have to 'remember' -every- variable name/etc. You can just auto-complete them to completion. This helps to centralize your constants and only have a single place where you need to change string values.

so for example (and this only has the 1 value listed)

```
public class ContactsContract {
    public class CommonDataKinds {
        public class Phone {
            public static final String NUMBER = "number";
        }
    }    

}
```

---

Further info:

Here is the javadoc for the file in question:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Here is the Source code of that file (from grep code):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/provider/ContactsContract.java

(And as you can see my above code snippet is correct except I forgot to make each class `final`... but I was close)

---

Here is another example that might be more clear:

I wrote this code (not my repo... code is in my PhD adviser's repo and was used in the Coursera Course https://www.coursera.org/course/posasoftware )

Our [MOOC Schema](https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/POSA-14/blob/1f0aa0967cec49aad56986f7af604d02a127bd75/assignments/week-7-assignment-6/iRemember/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/MoocSchema.java)

[A file that uses it](https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/POSA-14/blob/1f0aa0967cec49aad56986f7af604d02a127bd75/assignments/week-7-assignment-6/iRemember/src/edu/vuum/mocca/storage/StoryCreator.java) (that is public and learners didn't have to write)

As you can see, the benefit of the schema class is that it allows the 2nd class to 'make use of' the internal string values of the schema without having to handle strings directly. There is still a tight coupling between these files, but it allows you to make changes to the DB (such as fixing a typo, etc) in a single place, without having to go through your entire code looking for strings to replace. (also cuts down on typos elsewhere in the code).

Comment: You are quite right, and I have corrected my mistake in my original post. It was an error I made when I originally entered the post here on StackOverflow. I am, however, getting data from the database as I am also populating a List<Type> at the same time.

Comment: I've explained in further detail about the Contacts "schema" (a schema is 'essentially' the 'model' by which the underlying DB(and therefore its related Content Provider(CP)) are defined. (technically the Schema file could/(should? <- some opinions) have some 'helper' methods... which is beyond what a 'model' should have... but that is besides the point)  If a content provider makes a Schema file public like Contacts has done, then you will use the constants within it to know what fields/tables/etc to pull data out of the CP with. Then use @Marko's answer w/ SimpleCursorAdapter to get the data